Anaconda Windows Installer UAC NSIS flag
When I manually execute the Windows installer for Anaconda to install it for "All Users (required admin privileges)", the following parameters are specified by the manufacturer: /UAC:301B0 /NCRC. /NCRC for NSIS installers is clear, but what does /UAC:301B0 mean? What is the purpose of /UAC:301B0 or ‘301B0’?

/UAC refers to User Account Control settings, specifically, it sets the UAC level to 301B0. The value likely corresponds to a specific UAC configuration, but without further context, it’s challenging to determine its exact purpose.

It's a handle to something in the parent process so they can communicate. It can change every time you run the installer and has no meaning you can infer anything from.
